# Splitting field in $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

I want to find the splitting field in$\mathbb{C}$ of $x^4-4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I solved for the zeros, which is $i\sqrt2, -i\sqrt2, \sqrt2, -\sqrt2$, so the splitting field, say $E$, is just $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$, or should it just be $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt2)$?

If $E=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$, then I get the order of $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is  $$[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt2, \sqrt2):\mathbb{Q}]=4$$

Please give me some input. I am still trying to grasp the definition/ methods of dealing with splitting field.

Comment: You should check that indeed $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: ok, that's what I thought, then its order over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 2, right?

Comment: No, then the degree is in fact $4$ as you said originally (adding each of $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$ correspond to degree $2$ extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fields are the same. You can check this by noting that $i\sqrt{2} \in {\mathbb Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ and, conversely, that $i \in {\mathbb Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.

And, indeed, $[{\mathbb Q}(i,\sqrt{2}) : {\mathbb Q}] = 4$. This follows, for instance, from the fact that $x^4 - 4$ is irreducible over ${\mathbb Q}$. You could also reason that since $[{\mathbb Q}(i) : {\mathbb Q}] = 2$ and $[{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2}) : {\mathbb Q}] = 2$ and ${\mathbb Q}(i) \neq {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$, you must have that $[{\mathbb Q}(i,\sqrt{2}) : {\mathbb Q}] = 4$.